# How does GitHub/GitLab "inline" issues editing work

Tags: javascript, jquery

How does GitHub/GitLab implement real time issues editing? When pressing *e* or the *Edit* button the issue description becomes a form, but I see no ajax call or whatever... How does it load the HTML which replaces the *static* content?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is already there. It is the "static" content you are already looking at.

The basics of it are you can apply a `contenteditable` property to any HTML element and it becomes editable.

```html
<div contenteditable>
 You can edit this. Click me.
</div>
```

I haven't looked at their code specifically, but they are likely either doing something like this, or they are loading it into a WYSIWYG. Either way though, they're likely using the direct HTML that is already there for the content, hence no AJAX calls needed.

```js
const content = document.querySelector('div');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  content.setAttribute('contenteditable', !content.contenteditable);
});
```

```html
<button>Toggle Edit</button>
<div>
  <h1>Hello There</h1>
  <p>This is content.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: ok but what about  all the input elements, the form, the additional events which could be  bound to the form elements?

Comment: You'd have to handle them all yourself, but  it's the same basic idea. You could also just grab the `.innerHTML` of the element and throw that into a `<textarea>` for an even simpler version.